# Mobile design are not same with firefox Responsive Design Mode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have some issue with my responsive web design.

I'm filtering woocommerce hooks `woocommerce_get_price_html`,

My code give the following output bellow:

- if reseller price is set, return reseller price
- else return

The code above working fine in firefox Responsive Web Design, but when I'm test my web design on mobile device, the output are not same with Responsive Design Mode.

Any idea to test mobile design on desktop?
Thank you

Comment: For testing your responsive design on a desktop browser, just resize the browser window.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for advice, I will try. Hope this help

Comment: Why not use the mobile emulators available on the web?

Answer (score 1):

install google chrome and use developer tools by right click =>inspect in the page you want to develop as you see in the image it have good option.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1IAJ.png)